# How to disable a hardware from being grabbed by hid-multitouch driver

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have a kortek touch screen hardware with the following info:

```
VendorId  = 2965
ProductId = 5023
```

This hardware is driven by `hid-multitouch` driver by default.
I do not require multitouch functionality as of now.

I want to use the hardware in single touch mode and therefore want to use `hid-generic` driver.

To stop `hid-multitouch` from driving this touch screen hardware I commented out the following lines in linux kernel driver code `drivers/hid/hid-multitouch.c`

```
/* Generic MT device */
//{ HID_DEVICE(HID_BUS_ANY, HID_GROUP_MULTITOUCH, HID_ANY_ID, HID_ANY_ID) },
```

Since the Kortek hardware entry was not specifically listed in this device table so I disabled the driver for generic devices by commenting out the generic device entry.

But this does not work and `hid-multitouch` still grabs the hardware.

I would like to know what changes do I need to make to disable `'hid-multitouch` driver from grabbing this hardware.

Comment: Can you confirm that the newly-built kernel is being loaded?  Is this hid-multitouch driver a loadable module or built-in?

Comment: newly built kernel is indeed loaded. It is loadable module but the module is loaded during system bootup. Btw, I am using Ubuntu 16.0.4 LTS running kernel 4.4.0 series

Comment: You can try blacklisting the loadable module and see if the kernel refuses to load it, although this is not the optimal solution.  Alternatively, you can rename the module, although this is slightly more of a hack.

Comment: I don't want to blacklist the module. 
Renaming is not a good solution.

Comment: Perhaps you should try disabling CONFIG_HID_MULTITOUCH in `make menuconfig` and rebuild.  You could also comment-out that piece of the Makefile at that driver location (to debug).

Comment: @Monku, either you do easy way (blacklisting module), or much harder up to writting multitouch support.

Comment: @AndyShevchenko I want just this hardware(Kortek touchscreen) not to be grabbed by `hid-multitouch`. I don't want to blacklist the hid-multitouch module. What I am looking for is some way to disable this hardware from being grabbed by `hid-multitouch` without blacklisting.